# How to create a script that can migrate database to another normalized database

Tags: mysql, database, database-migration

I have an existing system with hundred thousands of data. I need to migrate it to another database but different structure. How can i create a script that will migrate database to a different structure.

I tried csv but i need to make some columns to foreign key because the new database is much normalized

example

[image]

Comment: Are the two databases on the same MySQL server? And is the `id` in the `categories` table auto-incrementing?

Comment: Connect to both databases, save table to array and insert it to the new database. What's the problem?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware same server but categories in the new database is set already. just need to match the id

Comment: @Dominik php script? or native mysql syntax?

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution in pure MySQL. It takes into account that you commented that the: *"categories in the new database is set already"*. You can do an [insert-select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) like this:

```
INSERT INTO database2.products (id, category_id, name)
SELECT p.id, 
       (SELECT c.id FROM database2.categories AS c WHERE p.category = c.category),
       p.name
FROM database1.products as p
```

The special trick is in the sub-query where the catagory fields are compared.

**WARNING: Untested query. Make a backup first!**

Comment: where do i run the syntax? i tried it in phpmyadmin but it says no database selected. i tried to run it inside one of the database and got error

Comment: @KevinLeonardSoldevilla Runing it phpmyadmin seems like a good place to start. I cannot suggest another way forward if all you say is: "I got an error". I don't have your database, and cannot guess what error that might be. It is possibly best to ask a new question, with a sample of the database, the query, and the errors. I won't be monitoring SO all the time.

Comment: no problem i got it already. im running it on phpmyadmin console. thank you @KIKO Software